# Localizing the JFileChooser "All Files" string

Tags: java, swing, locale, jfilechooser

I am working on a java application with a JFileChooser and the user is able to switch languages.

```
Locale.setDefault( Locale.ENGLISH );
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.showOpenDialog( null );

Locale.setDefault( Locale.CHINA );
JFileChooser.setDefaultLocale( Locale.CHINA );
JFileChooser chinese_chooser = new JFileChooser();
chinese_chooser.showOpenDialog( null );
```

The second file chooser to appear is in Chinese except for the "All Files" string in the drop down box. If I comment out the first section of code the file chooser appears correctly with all the strings translated.

Is this a bug in java or do I need to set the locale somewhere else?

How can I get the translated file chooser to appear correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[I found something that might help you here.](http://www.coderanch.com/t/475470/GUI/java/customizing-JFIleChooser)  Here's how you change the "All Files" string:

```
UIManager.put("FileChooser.acceptAllFileFilterText","abc4");
```

Just put this right before you set the default locale to `Locale.CHINA`.  It's lame that it's not changed in the locale, but maybe that will give you the work around you need for this to work out for you.

Comment: The String is included in the locale but for some reason it is not being updated. This worked for me: `UIManager.put("FileChooser.acceptAllFileFilterText",UIManager.get( "FileChooser.acceptAllFileFilterText", Locale.CHINA ));`

Comment: @Kara it's a bug, indeed: the default fileFilter used by BasicFileChooserUI doesn't return the localized version of the string, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17446693/203657